# Are there more efficient ways to search for help/documentation than Google/SO/...?

Tags: productivity, search-engine

Google sometimes come up with irrelevant links, not everything is available on SO, there are cases where the local documentation is also annoying to look through... Are there other efficient ways you use to search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Practise your Google-fu. Google is pretty awesome, but it's not magic. Sometimes you'll need to use search operators to get better answers, especially on some code phrases that can be difficult to search. Check out the [Google Guide](http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators_reference.html), for example.

If I know where the answer is, I might use the site: operator, or if I need something citable I often use inurl:edu. Google Code is handy for finding examples, and I use it to search for APIs sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most useful pieces of advice I can give is to start using [Google Bookmarks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Bookmarks). These results will appear when you are searching Google. I really like how (unlike other bookmarking services) this is set and forget. The bookmark sharing could be improved however.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly just use google with enough keywords to get the directly to the documentation without having to pull up giant RAM eating pages like the [entire Java 6 class list](http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api).

Comment: Your link points to the Java **6** class list.

Comment: **ZOMG! FRAMES!!**

Answer (score 0):

For programming issues I tend to look at bookmark websites using tags for example - http://www.delicious.com/tag/programming

Another resource to check out are books, sometimes a good book about a topic can give you just what you are looking for. So [Google Book Search](http://books.google.com/) is a good way to identify the books that might be of help.